# MySQL Procedure / MySQL Function

Tags: mysql

I am still relatively new to MySQL and am stuck on a bit of data engineering.

I have a table with following:

```
Event_ID, Minutes, EventCode
```

I have multiple rows with same Event_ID and what event has occurred (eventcode) along with when in minutes (Minutes).

What I want to do is output to a new table the sequence of events based on the minutes for an event_id:

Eg:

Source:

```
Event_ID,   Minutes, EventCode
12,         45,         A
12,         49,         B
12,         78,         A
```

WOuld be transformed into:

```
12, 45, A, 1
12, 49, B, 2
12, 78, B, 3
```

So the last column shows the sequence. Although it can be assmed the source table is sorted by event_id following by minutes I would rather a solution that worked for it to be unsorted if possible

Some pointers would be great!

Thanks

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using please

Comment: which version are you using, if above 8.0 you can use the row_number() function

Comment: if under 8 here is a tutorial on how to emulate row_number() https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-row_number/

Answer (score 3):

Im MySQL 8 and higher you can use the `row_number()` window function.

```
SELECT event_id,
       minutes,
       eventcode,
       row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY event_id
                          ORDER BY minutes)
       FROM elbat;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:
`select event_id, minutes, eventcode, @rownum:=@rownum+1 No from elbat, (SELECT @rownum:=0) r;`